# How to set up elpy to use python3?

Tags: python, osx, ipython, elpy

When setting up my emacs for a new work environment, I am unable to get the elpy configuration to correctly use python 3. I have installed all of the required packages in `/usr/local/bin` and have installed them using python3.

Right now, when I run elpy-config I am getting the following:

```
Virtualenv........: None
RPC Python........: 2.7.6 (/usr/bin/python)
Interactive Python: python (/usr/bin/python)
Emacs.............: 24.5.1
Elpy..............: 1.9.0
Jedi..............: 0.9.0
Rope..............: Not found (0.10.2 available)
Importmagic.......: 0.1.3
Autopep8..........: 0.1.3
Syntax checker....: Not found (pyflakes)
```

I would like to have RPC Python be ipython3 and the same for the interactive. For the purposes of this question, assume my .emacs file is blank.

Comment: I hope you mean /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 28):

You can conffigure `elpy-rpc-python-command`. If you want Python3 you can set it like this.

```
(setq elpy-rpc-python-command "python3")
```

**Update**

Create python3 virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper from terminal

```
$ mkvirtualenv test -p /usr/bin/python3
```

and then install required packages

```
$ pip install rope jedi importmagic autopep8 flake8
```

Now go to emacs, activate virtualenv and run `M-x elpy-config`

```
M-x pyvenv-workon test
M-x elpy-config
```

If you want to have `ipython` as your REPL, you can put this function in you config

```
(elpy-use-ipython)
```

or

```
(elpy-use-ipython "python3")
```

Note: `elpy-use-ipython` is deprecated. Use

```
(setenv "IPY_TEST_SIMPLE_PROMPT" "1")
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython3"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i")
```

or `ipython` based on your version.

Comment: Doing this and then going back into the config says that python3 is not recognized and Jedi, Importmagic, and autopep8 are now marked as `not found`

Comment: You have to set full path to `python3`. If you are using ubuntu, you can use `/usr/bin/python3`. In any case, it is better if you create python3 virtual env, activate that env and install those packages. Updated answer

Comment: If you have ipython installed for Python2 and ipython3 installed for Python3, then you can use the ipython3 REPL with `(elpy-use-ipython "ipython3")` assuming that's in your path.

Comment: `(elpy-use-ipython)` is deprecated; see https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#interpreter-setup

Comment: The above made it worse as adam stated.  I made a virtual env and did all the imports. elpy is not finding anything and insistse on stil suping elpy/repc-venv/bin/python as well which is what it was complaining about in the first place

Comment: Does ELPY have a variable inspector or a way to see my variables?

Comment: I don't think elpy has a variable inspector. You can use `helm-semantic-or-imenu` function to view variables, functions etc. @EmmanuelGoldstein

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this by modifying the python shell configuration from python to python3 in elpy-config

1. `M-x elpy-config` to enter the configuration page of elpy
2. if you scroll down you will see groups with [+] signs, toggle the Python one and find the shell interpreter option: `Option Python Shell Interpreter` is the one you are looking for.
3. If you click (or Enter in terminal version) on the Option button you will be able to edit the part "python" to "python3"
4. Apply and save, and restart emacs

Comment: I did this and `elpy-config` no longer opens: it says it cannot find `python3`. However, `python3` *is* in my path because I can issue it as a command in terminal no problem. For some reason emacs isn't actually capturing my full path. Is this a feature or a bug? I noticed it in many other packages requiring inferior shells as well.

Comment: never mind, I'm on OSX and using gui emacs, and there's a really bad gotcha here that gui emacs (as opposed to terminal emacs) [doesn't capture my PATH variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606954/path-and-exec-path-set-but-emacs-does-not-find-executable).

Answer (score 2):

Set the interpreter variable in your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i")
```

Taken from [elpy manual](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#interactive-python)