# Set multiple dir-local variables for the same mode

Tags: directory-local-variables

I understand from [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables#toc2), that I can use dir-locals.el to customize modes, such as given in the example:

```
      ;; Warn about spaces used for indentation:
      (haskell-mode . ((eval . (highlight-regexp "^ *"))))
      (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")))
      (java-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")))
      ("src/imported"
       . ((nil . ((change-log-default-name . "ChangeLog.local"))))))
```

However, all of these make 1 change per language-mode.  I would like to make multiple changes to the same mode, `python-mode`, and I think my syntax is only keeping the first one.

What's the right syntax to combine these two variables settings in `dir-locals.el`?

I have:

```
;; misc
((python-mode
  (python-shell-buffer-name . "Python[This Project]")))

;; set the local pyvenv
((python-mode . ((pyvenv-activate . "./envs/default")
                 )))

;; find local pylintrc vs global
((python-mode . ((eval . (lambda ()  (setq flycheck-pylintrc ".pylintrc"))))))
```

Other refs consulted:

- [How to set up elpy to use python3?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/how-to-set-up-elpy-to-use-python3)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288836/elpy-and-pylint-where-should-a-pylintrc-file-be-placed-in-order-to-customize-py
- https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1s9f9y/using_a_functionhook_instead_of_dir_local/
- https://seandavi.github.io/post/2018-12-08-directory-local-variables-for-custom-emacs-projects/
- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/chromite/+/master/.dir-locals.el
- [How to use .dir-locals.el with Projectile?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24907/how-to-use-dir-locals-el-with-projectile)

Comment: For each mode you can have an alist. The alist can specify any number of settings. See the example with `nil` (which stands for any mode) in the Emacs Wiki page you cite. Change `nil` to `python-mode` and you have an example of setting multiple things for Python mode.

Comment: Could you point me to an example?

Comment: It's like that TV game show where the contestants are given an answer and have to respond with a matching question.

Answer (score 4):

The dir-locals file contains an alist of nested alists. This would be the correct form for your example of setting multiple variables for `python-mode`:

```
((python-mode . ((python-shell-buffer-name . "Python[This Project]")
                 (pyvenv-activate . "./envs/default")
                 (eval . (lambda ()  (setq flycheck-pylintrc ".pylintrc")))))
 (other-mode . (... ALIST)))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is already answered, but just for another perspective:

If you just want to avoid syntax problems or view correct syntax, you can call `add-dir-local-variable`. It prompts for a mode, then a variable, then a setting. You can do this twice for the one mode, then open your `.dir-locals.el` file and view the correct syntax.

Comment: n.b. This works best since Emacs 27.1, when the command was changed so that it generated the preferred dotted-pair notation.